# Upgrade option unavailable when upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 from a USB stick

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, 12.04

I created a USB startup disk from ISO and booted using that to upgrade my 11.10 installation. But when I am not able to select Upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04. The radio button cannot be selected. I am doing a Network upgrade now.

Comment: I can't. Hopefully someone else will find this useful. It might also help me figure out why I am having another problem with my installation.

Answer (score 0):

If are trying that upgrade with a "live USB" then you can't. Though if you have the alternate iso, then you could avoid wasting a CD by mounting the ISO as a drive with a command like:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom
sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom
```

Then to start the upgrade enter:

```
gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```